What is the the maximum and minimum amount of nodes in a heap
The title of my question says all that is needed. Some may argue that this is a duplicate question, because some years ago, this same question was made, but I couldn't understand the explanation, then a similar question was made again, but for a d-ary heap, but I couldn't understand it neither.
The best I could get was from a post on math exchange, for me, it sounded more clear and I was trully conviced that I understod it, until the moment I tried to proof by myself. Here is how far I could make:
Since the amount of nodes in a heap are given by a geometric progression:
$2^{0}+2^{1}+2^{2}+...2^{h}$
We only need to calculate its finite geometric series $S_{h}$.
$S_{h} = a_{0} \times \frac{1-r^{h}}{1-r}$
to find out the value of $r$ we can divide any $a_{i}$ by $a_{i-1}$, so, for the sake of simplicity, we can choose $a_{i}$ being equal to $a_{1}$ and $a_{i-1}$ being equal to $a_{0}$, so we would have:
$r = \frac{2^{1}}{2^{0}} \rightarrow r= 2$
Applying this value to the formula, we would have:
$S_{h} = 2^{0} \times \frac{1-2^{h}}{1-2}$
$S_{h} = 1 \times \frac{1-2^{h}}{1-2}$
$S_{h} = \frac{1-2^{h}}{-1}$
$-1 \times (S_{h}) = -1 \times (\frac{1-2^{h}}{-1})$
$-S_{h} = (1-2^{h})$
$-1 \times (-S_{h}) =  -1 \times (1-2^{h})$
$S_{h} = -1+2^{h}$
$S_{h} = 2^{h}-1$
At the first glance, I really thought I managed to proof it (although with help), than it turned out that my answer is incorrect because it simply doesn't work. For example, for a full tree of $h=2$ (starting from $h=0$) the formula "says" it has 3 nodes, when, in fact it has 7 nodes. Looking on the answer on math exchange I saw that the guy ended up with :
$S_{h} = 2^{0} \times \frac{1-2^{h+1}}{1-2}$
not
$S_{h} = 2^{0} \times \frac{1-2^{h}}{1-2}$
and I have no idea why this two on the numerator is raised by the power of $h+1$ and not just $h$. So I would like help with this.
Also, I don't know exactly how I can proof the "minimum amount of nodes in a heap" part of the question, so I also would appreciate any help or insight on this part of the question.
P.S.:
Please be prolific on the math, I am not good at it and some steps that may be obvious for you, problably won't be for me.

It feels like there is a lot going on in this question. Is there a reason why (2^h) - 1 isn't sufficient and therefore needs further proof?

@KiithNabaal It is wrong, that's why isn't sufficient, but I agree with you, I said too much, maybe it would had been better if I were more straightfoward

You used the wrong formula for the sum of a geometric series.
$r^0 + r^1 + \dots + r^h$ equals $\frac{1-r^{h+1}}{1-r}$, not $\frac{1-r^h}{1-r}$.

You can see that the original formula cannot be right by chosing say r = 1000, and the sum of the series should obviously by a tiny bit greater than the last element, which is r^n = r^(n+1) / r.
